# Jenkins Oracle authentication

Tags: oracle, authentication, jenkins

I have created a Jenkins pipeline for PLSQL base code deployment. This works find on the Dev or Test databases as we know the Oracle password.

But, for production Oracle database we do not want to enter the password. Hence, is there any way we can deploy the passwordless Oracle release from Jenkins pipeline i.e. by SSH public/private key pair? Certificate - a PKCS#12 certificate file and optional password? or if via Oracle wallet?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess you have a Jenkins pipeline which is running shell scripts, and in those shell scripts you are running sqlplus. If you want to avoid passwords in connections by sqlplus, Oracle Wallet is the answer.

In my current Jenkins configuration SSH connections are done by SSH-key between the servers, and connections to the database are using Oracle Wallet.

Remember that if you use Oracle Wallet, you need to setup the TNS_ADMIN variable to the location where your tnsnames.ora file contains the wallet details. Also remember to modify your sqlnet.ora to include all wallet details.

A good article on how to setup the wallet

https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/secure-external-password-store-10gr2

Comment: Thank you for the answer